# How to invoke each function in a row in a pandas column by an argument at the respective index?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to call a different function in column B with a different row value in column A.

I am not sure how to do this in pandas, but I don't want to iterate through the rows - just combine the rows and get their respective values - similar to what I have tried below.

Can this be done?

See the code below for what I have already tried

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [i for i in range(160)], 'B': [lambda a: i * a for i in range(160)]})

# call each function in each row matched with the respective row in the other column
df['B'](df['A'])
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is a really weird design. Are you trying to vectorize/parallelize a bunch of operations?

Comment: yes - it's a POC for a more complex/unusual piece of code - I just wanted to scaffold some basic stuff for performance benchmarking

Comment: All I can say is that storing functions in a pandas series is not a good idea, and you will not have any benefits from the library by doing so. You'll be using a collection with bunch of overhead (heavy memory consumption, indexing etc) for operations you won't be able to use. Better to use `threading` library and work with threads, or use pure python lists and `zip` if you need this single-threaded.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - the actual amount of functions is far less - but still needs some parallelising. I will keep zip in mind too. I will be benchmark test all the options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very weird situation, but you can do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['B'](x['A']), axis=1)
```

which essentially iterate through the rows, just looks better. Output:

```
0          0
1        159
2        318
3        477
4        636
       ...  
155    24645
156    24804
157    24963
158    25122
159    25281
Length: 160, dtype: int64
```